# Assembly - first bit in bit array

Tags: assembly

I need 2 bits with offset 6 from bit array.

```
mov eax, [bitarray]; // get address of bit array
shr eax, 6; // clear first 6 bits
shl eax, 30 // clear last 30 bits
shr eax, 30; // move that 2 bits back to start
```

now in eax is these 2 bits i need, right?

When i have memory started from 0 (one unit is one bit), then bit on position 0 will be after load into register eax in most right place or most left place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the two shifts at the end you could have use a bitwise `AND`:

```
AND EAX,3  ; Keep the original value of the two least significant bits; all
           ; other bits in EAX are cleared.
```

The left-most bit is the most significant one, and the right-most bit the least significant one.

Comment: yes i know left-most is the most significant, but if there is little endian, then in memory that left-most bit in register is where? On position 0 or position 7?

Comment: Endianness doesn't affect the order of bits within a byte. It affects the order of bytes with a word/dword/etc. The most significant bit of a byte is bit 7.

Comment: oh i see it now, if you are doing AND with 3

Comment: michael: yes, so first bit in memory isn't first bit in eax?

Answer (score 0):

mov eax, [bitarray]

bitmask?

```
mov eax,[bitarray]
mov ebx,C0         ;11000000 binary
and ax,bx
```

Comment: i think this is bad, it should be ANDed with value 3 (00000011)